# Fix module routes manually after installing PATCH SUPEE 6788 + toolbox fix

Tags: patches, supee-6788, enterprise-1.14

After running https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox fix for patch supee 6788 some routes still go to 404 page.

The fixSUPEE6788.log says for those cases "Admin routes for the module will have to be fixed manually". I don't know how to do that (replace what where).

i.e

```
2015-11-05T20:48:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): Found affected module: Unirgy_DropshipPo
2015-11-05T20:48:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): Found route tag 'udpoadmin'.
```

Original route XML:

```
<udpoadmin>
   <use>admin</use>
   <args>
      <module>Unirgy_DropshipPo_Adminhtml</module>
      <frontName>udpoadmin</frontName>
   </args>
</udpoadmin>

2015-11-05T20:48:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): ERROR: Unirgy_DropshipPo module route already includes _Adminhtml. Admin routes for the module will have to be fixed manually.
2015-11-05T20:48:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): To be replaced with:

<adminhtml>
   <args>
      <modules>
         <udpoadmin before="Mage_Adminhtml">Unirgy_DropshipPo_Adminhtml</udpoadmin>
      </modules>
   </args>
</adminhtml>
```

I'm looking at the config.xml file for this module and it has the changed applied (last code below "To be replaced with").

Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
Unigry uDropship modules needed to be updated (as rob3000 answered mentions). In this case the extensions have an automatic updater (system->tools->unigry installer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should see if the modules have been updated rather than changing them manually. If there is no update for the module then you don't need to action this straight away. Magento added a config option in the patch:

```
<extensions_compatibility_mode>1</extensions_compatibility_mode>
```

Located in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`

This means that you can update your 3rd party modules as they become available.

Alternatily if you really wanted to patch the modules you can be editing the `etc/config.xml` file located in the module directory. So for example `Unirgy_DropshipPo` will most likely be located in `app/code/community/Unirgy` or `app/code/local/Unirgy`. You then need to change:

From:

```
<use>admin</use>
<args>
    <module>Unirgy_DropshipPo_Adminhtml</module>
    <frontName>udpoadmin</frontName>
</args>
```

To:

```
<args>
    <modules>
       <udpoadmin before="Mage_Adminhtml">Unirgy_DropshipPo_Adminhtml</udpoadmin>
    </modules>
</args>
```

Comment: Even with original code and "extensions_compatibility_mode = 0" it is still showing a 404 page. I believe admin routes are created differently now, I just don't know how to fix them manually.

Comment: ok so in the `adminhtml.xml` you should see where the pages are defined which they should have an action something like `<action>adminhtml/dropship</action>` This will point to a controller in `Unirgy_DropshipPo_controllers_Adminhtml_DropShipContoller.php`